# CSS3 translateZ is not in mac Safari 8.0.3

Tags: css, safari, transform

It works perfectly in FF/Chrome.

```
<div id="css-transform-container">
        <img src="/static/img/shamegallery/Abraham_Beame.gif">
```

```
#css-transform-container {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  perspective: 180px;
}

#css-transform-container img {
  cursor: zoom-in;
  transform: translateZ(-200px);
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(-200px);
  -o-transform: translateZ(-200px);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(-200px);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(-200px);
}
```

I am sure it supports the translateZ function because I tried other sites and my Safari displays the translation with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try to use preserve-3d.**

Look below at this exemple:

```
#main {
       display: block;
       position: absolute;
       width: 400px; height: 400px;
       border: thin solid red;
       top: 10px;
       left: 10px;
       -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
       -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
    }
```

Check this too: http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d